# Unity TextMeshPro 3D Object messing up with normal UI Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, text, 3d

I have a 3D Object TextMeshPro disabled in my scene, and a normal UI Canvas with a button working.

When I enable the 3D Object TextMeshPro, the Text (TMP) from the button disappear... the button still works, but no text in it at all...

Worse, this button changes my whole scene to another one, Menu, with lots of buttons with Texts (TMP)... all of them disapeared... yes, in another scene, just because the enabling of that 3D Object TextMeshPro.

Any ideias?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: yeah, so does to me...

Comment: Help -> Report a bug